# message sent to deallocated instance 0x600000147e80 error by clicking sub view event in container view OS X Swift

Tags: swift, macos

I am new in os x programming. I am using swift to developing my mac app. In my app home screen contains a `Container` view and some `NSButtons`. By clicking on the buttons the `NSViewControllers` (created in storyboard) appear on the `ContainerView`. This is done by the code below:

```
self.ContainerView.subviews.removeAll()
let myViewController = iR_DELEGATE.GoToPage("Questions",container: ContainerView)
self.ContainerView.addSubview(myViewController.view)
```

the `GoToPage` function code is:

```
func GoToPage(identify: String,container: NSView) -> NSViewController
{
   let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) as NSStoryboard
   let myViewController = storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identify) as! NSViewController
   myViewController.view .setFrameSize(CGSize.init(width: container.frame.width, height: container.frame.height))
   return myViewController
}
```

The problem is when I click on the button or select the table's view in the sub view controller that displayed in container view the app crash with error:

> message sent to deallocated instance 0x600000147e80

I got this error by enable zombie objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your crash is likely caused by the fact that the view controller is deallocated almost immediately after you created it.

A view controller holds a reference to its view, but not the other way around. When you add `myViewController.view` as a subview, it is retained and displayed. In the meantime, `myViewController` itself is not retained by anything, so it is removed from memory after the variable is last used.

You probably have your view controller as target to button's action. When you tap the button, it wants to send the action to the view controller, but it has been already deallocated, and it crashes.

To solve it, you need to keep the reference to `myViewController` to keep it from being deallocated earlier than needed. Either just store it in a variable, or consider using child view controllers for that purpose: [https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005253-CH1-SW34](http://Managing%20Child%20View%20Controllers%20in%20a%20Custom%20Container)

Comment: Thanks.. It Solve my problem